# How to add 2 String into array conditionally and print those value one down the other

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have an array that is empty initially
later put some conditions and print those items

```
const myItems= []
-----other code goes here
myItems = someCondition : "A B" : "A"
```

if someCondition is true should look like one or the other down

```
   "A"

   "B"
```

else

```
  "A"
```

Comment: do you want to add two items or a string `'A B'`?

Comment: @Nina Scholz i want to add String 'A B'

Answer (score 1):

Just push one of the expressions.

```
const items = [];

items.push(condition ? 'A B' : 'A');
```

Comment: i want to add String 'A B'

Answer (score 1):

You could do use this:

```js
var myItems = [];
let someCondition = Math.random() > 0.5;
myItems = someCondition ? "A B" : "A";

myItems.split(' ').forEach(e => console.log(e));
```

Answer (score 1):

you could simply do this :

```
const myItems = [];
myItems.push((condition ? "A B" : "A").splite(" "));
```

Comment: it says  Type 'string[] | "AB' is not assignable to type 'string'.   Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.